# error using Hilo example app in Visual C 2010

Tags: c++, hilo

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and I get the following when I compile the example project in Chapter 2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff795784.aspx

The error is this:
'uicc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.
3>
3>Build FAILED.

I searched for the file "uicc.exe" in my computer. It does not exist apparently. I checked the version of my SDK and it seems to be v7.0A.

So... what do I do?

Also...if my application is requiring this file "uicc.exe" and my computer does not have it... does that mean that potential target computers will not have this file either?

I want my applications to work on any target Windows 7 or above computer, without the user having to install stuff previously.

EDIT:
OKAY it turns out I need a different version of the SDK.

My new question is this: How do I uninstall the Windows 7 SDK I have, without uninstalling or affecting Visual Studio? I tried add/remove programs but oddly SDK for Windows is not listed (just a whole lot of other stuff, including Silverlight SDK, but not Windows SDK).

So, how do I uninstall it so I can install the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uicc.exe is Ribbons compiler, which is not included in Visual Studio 2010 SDK (v7.0A). Must download another version of SDK. The following link clarifies the issue and contains download link:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533794/ribbon-compiler-tool-uicc-is-missing-from-included-windows-sdk